# Search doesn't display posts with images

Tags: posts, images, search

I’m new and need help with something. I am making a website for a business that wants to display all their instruments (photos with their measurements) as shown below.

https://ibb.co/gSf3eF

Then they want that when someone searches for an instrument, for example “piano”, only this post shows up.
My current search does this, the problem you can see below is that the result found is displayed very poorly. Title and measurements are displayed all in one line and there is no image.

https://ibb.co/bLyjmv

What I would like for it to show is the same thing when you scroll through all instruments, except only the matching ones would be displayed. I hope you guys can understand what I mean!

I am on localhost (the client will give me access to his host and domain after our meeting). Theme is Sydney (free version). I have many plugins installed, the search one is called “Search & Filter”. I have also installed:

– Contact form 7
– GTranslate
– Page Builder by SiteOrigin
– Post Types Order
– SMTP Mailer
– Social Media and Share Icons (Ultimate Social Media)
– Sydney Toolbox
– Wordfence Security
– WP Google Maps
– WPGlobus
– Yoast SEO

The posts’ format is Image, no featured image, title ‘Guitar’ for example, and this is the code for it (piano is similar):

```
<div id="pl-312" class="panel-layout">
<div id="pg-312-0" class="panel-grid panel-has-style">
<div class="panel-row-style panel-row-style-for-312-0" style="padding: 100px 0;" data-overlay="true">
<div id="pgc-312-0-0" class="panel-grid-cell" data-weight="1">
<div id="panel-312-0-0-0" class="widget_text so-panel widget widget_custom_html panel-first-child panel-last-child" data-index="0" data-style="{">
<div class="widget_text panel-widget-style panel-widget-style-for-312-0-0-0" style="text-align: left;" data-headings-color="#443f3f" data-title-color="#443f3f">
<h3 class="widget-title">Guitar</h3>
<div><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-313" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Electric-Guitar-Clip-Art-PNG.png" alt="" width="958" height="510" /></div>
<div class="textwidget custom-html-widget">Width: 150cm<br />
Height: 180cm</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I hope this is enough info and you can help me out! I have posted this on other sites and got no help so far but I really need to figure this out ASAP! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you've provided is the displayed code on the website.  You'll need to edit the single.php and make it match the archive/index page of your theme.  search the index the code you want, place it in your post single.php.

Comment: np.  Mind if I place it as an answer so you can mark answered to close the question?

Comment: Okay it's added.  Please click the check box to the left of the answer so it can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've provided is the displayed code on the website. You'll need to edit the single.php and make it match the archive/index page of your theme. search the index the code you want, place it in your post single.php.

Good luck and let me know if you have other questions.